# Django Autogenerate links with new pages

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Another inherited Django project question.  I would like to make it so that each time a page is created (current example being https://bar.blah.net/detail/588/) that I can make the format as such https://bar.blah.net/detail/majorVersion.minorVersion.number
so https://bar.blah.net/detail/21.2.9 is the result.  is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL patterns in Django can be anything you'd like; there's no convention. An easy way to do this is to add a permalink to your model that will calculate the format you're looking for.

You'll need to add a corresponding URL pattern to resolve the pattern to your view method or class as well, and how that is constructed largely depends on what you need to do with the parameters, if any you're passing in.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/instances/#the-permalink-decorator for an example on permalinks